# Log the HTTP request body when handling exceptions thrown by a `MediaTypeFormatter` which consumes the body

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2.2 controller action like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{id}")]
public void Update(int id, [FromBody] MyData data)  {}
```

HTTP clients make POST requests with an `application/json` message body, but sometimes the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter` can't parse the JSON which the body contains, and throws an exception before the controller action is ever invoked.

In that case, I would like to log both the exception that the formatter threw **and the JSON text which gave rise to the exception**.  I want this to happen in production (so as to properly account for the failure of failed requests), and therefore mere 'Tracing' is not an acceptable option here.  I feel that this is quite an acceptable thing to want.

At first blush, the global error handling facility [introduced with Web Api 2.1](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#global-error) would be just the thing here.  But in my `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionLogger`, there is no longer any opportunity to read the message body:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{        string body = await context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // essentially
    // body is an empty string!  the formatter already consumed it, and it's not available now
}
```

What options do I have for ASP.NET and/or Web Api 2 extension points to handle exceptions raised by the MediaTypeFormatter **and** log the actual request body?